# recovery time diodes

Tags: diodes

[image]During the recovery time the voltage VF in a diode is positive but the current IF is in the opposite direction. I think it’s very confusing, since all the current are flowing from high potential to low potential. I am really grateful that you may solve my problem since I didn’t find any explanation online. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your image is a mess, it has 2 curves which probably are both responses and the actual excitation is described only in a text or other images. In addition there should be a diagram for the circuit where the images are valid. If one should make a prima vista interpretation of what reverse recovery means and the only information was your image, the case would be hopeless. here's an older case which has more informative image: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/309483/how-charge-moves-through-a-diode-during-the-reverse-recovery-time

Comment: (continued) It as both the excitation and the response - the diode current is presented in circuit which has only the diode and a pulse source which outputs to the diode a DC which is turned suddenly to opposite polarity.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it’s very confusing, since all the current are flowing from
>   high potential to low potential.

The simplest way to imagine why this is the case is to add parasitic junction capacitance to a diode.

When a diode is forward biased this capacitance is charged to 0.7V.

But when you apply reversed biased voltage the discharge capacitor current will flow in the opposite direction. But the parasitic junction capacitance will "hold" positive voltage until capacitance is discharged.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your graph "is wrong" because, with a forward biased voltage on the diode, the current cannot possibly reverse. This graph is not alone; I see plenty on the internet with this confusing approach. I'm calling it a confusing approach because I'm giving them the benefit of the doubt that some words associated with those graphs may shed light on what they are trying to project. Here's my favourite drawing that shows the reverse recovery time: -

[image]

Picture from this [Rohm site](https://www.rohm.com/electronics-basics/diodes/types-of-diodes). The green area on the left is where the diode is forward voltage biased and, the red area on the right is when reverse voltage bias has occurred.

The graph shows the general difference between a "switching diode" and a diode used for rectification i.e. something like the 1N400x series.

### UPDATE

It's worth a simulation to see what is happening and I'm glad I did because, it sheds some light on the diode forward voltage remaining positive despite the current reversing and, it's clear that this is due to charge storage within the diode: -

[image]

It takes about 3 us for this 1N4003 diode to properly recover. But remember this is a simulation and not a worst case analysis.